# how to prevent automotive adding prefix on src of tag img

Tags: ajax, laravel

```
 Route::get('/message-list',[ChatController::class,'showMessageList'])->name('chat.messageList');
 Route::get('/getMessage-list',[ChatController::class,'getMessageList'])->name('getMessageList');
```

are my route

```
function changeDataBySelect(select) {
        var typeInput = $(select).val();
        if (typeInput) {
            $.ajax({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                url: "/chat/getMessage-list?type=" + typeInput,
                type: 'GET',
                data: {type:typeInput}, 
                success: function(response) {
                    if (response.status == 'success') {
                        var userRoom = convertJsonToHtml(response)
                        $('#message-list').html(userRoom);
                    }         
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log("Error: " + error);
        }
    }
```

this is my ajax code

```
 function convertJsonToHtml(json) { 
        var html = '';
        var userRooms = json.data.userRooms.data;
        userRooms.forEach( userRoom => {
            var typeKind = '';
            var setIcon = {
                TICKET: "ticket-icon-pc.svg",
                CONTENT: "guzu-icon-pc.svg",
                PROFILE: "profile-icon-pc.svg",
            };
            var iconIllus = '';
            if (userRoom.type == 'TICKET') {
                typeKind = 'チケット';
                iconIllus = setIcon.TICKET;
                
            } else if (userRoom.type == 'CONTENT') {
                typeKind = 'コンテンツ';
                iconIllus = setIcon.CONTENT;
            } else {
                typeKind = 'プロファイル';
                iconIllus = setIcon.PROFILE;
            }
            html += `
           <img class="message-list_icon" src="images/message-list/${iconIllus}">`
}
```

this is code to perform get data and convert to html

when access url. got an error message like following:

GET http://localhost:6990/chat/images/message-list/guzu-icon-pc.svg 404 (Not Found)

prefix "chat" automotive added

I tried to change route, url on ajax but cannot relsove.
please instruct to me how to resolve this trouble.
many thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You mentioned that a prefix "chat" is automatically added to the URL, which is likely causing the 404 error when trying to load the images. To resolve this issue, you can make sure that the URLs for loading images are correctly formed.
Since the images are located in the "images/message-list" directory and you're using Laravel's named routes, you can use the asset helper function to generate the correct URLs for your images.

```
 function convertJsonToHtml(json) { 
    var html = '';
    var userRooms = json.data.userRooms.data;
    userRooms.forEach( userRoom => {
        var typeKind = '';
        var setIcon = {
            TICKET: "ticket-icon-pc.svg",
            CONTENT: "guzu-icon-pc.svg",
            PROFILE: "profile-icon-pc.svg",
        };
        var iconIllus = '';
        if (userRoom.type == 'TICKET') {
            typeKind = 'チケット';
            iconIllus = setIcon.TICKET;
        } else if (userRoom.type == 'CONTENT') {
            typeKind = 'コンテンツ';
            iconIllus = setIcon.CONTENT;
        } else {
            typeKind = 'プロファイル';
            iconIllus = setIcon.PROFILE;
        }

        // asset() function to generate the image URL
        var imageUrl = "{{ asset('images/message-list') }}/" + iconIllus;

        html += `
        <img class="message-list_icon" src="${imageUrl}">`
    });
    return html; // here return the generated HTML
}
```

I hope it helps.